# Generate table of contents with links for GitHub markdown with pandoc

Tags: windows, github, table-of-contents, pandoc

How to generate table of contents with links for GitHub markdown with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)?

I tried `pandoc -f markdown_github --toc -s -S README.md -o new.md`
It does create a table of contents but it has no link to sections.

I'm trying to generate a table of contents [such as](http://pandoc.org/):

[image]

on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following command:

```
pandoc -f gfm --toc -s README.md -o r.md
```

as it worked fine for me with the latest version of `pandoc`.

With pandoc's own `README.md`, I got this ToC:

```
-   [Pandoc](#pandoc)
    -   [The universal markup
        converter](#the-universal-markup-converter)
    -   [Installing](#installing)
    -   [Documentation](#documentation)
    -   [Contributing](#contributing)
    -   [License](#license)
```

Comment: Thanks. Equivalent with a pipeline: `cat README.md | pandoc --from markdown  --toc -s  --to markdown -` (though it generates the entire file with contents).

Comment: Note: When I use `--toc` and open the file, I get a security prompt ("This document contains fields that may refer to other files.")

Comment: As long as pandoc only produces these fix link lists, consider [replacing the TOC by an out-of-the-box macro (see this SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948245/markdown-to-create-pages-and-table-of-contents/69460592#69460592). This way you can extend your markdown afterwards without bothering about the TOC.